# Support for Youtube clips urls

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am going over the documentation for the [Iframe Player Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), but I am not able to find any mention of playing the new [youtube clips](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10332730) in the player.

How can I play these clips on the player ?

Comment: The only way I've found is to read the opengraph meta tags (using something like opengraph.io, or manually via inspect element) and the embed URL to use in the iframe is included under a few different tags, "og:video:url" for instance.